# hadoop stuck at “running job”

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to running the hadoop word count program from the [doc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html). However the program stuck at `running job`

```
16/09/02 10:51:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/09/02 10:51:13 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/09/02 10:51:13 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/09/02 10:51:14 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/09/02 10:51:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
16/09/02 10:51:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1472783047951_0003
16/09/02 10:51:14 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1472783047951_0003
16/09/02 10:51:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hadoop-master:8088/proxy/application_1472783047951_0003/
16/09/02 10:51:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1472783047951_0003
```

And show http://hadoop-master:8088/proxy/application_1472783047951_0003/
[image]

And it runs a AppMaster on http://hadoop-slave2:8042, show it
[image]

However, since it stucks on WordCount, it also stuck on `Hive`

```
hive (default)> select a, b, count(1) as cnt from newtb group by a, b;
Query ID = hadoop_20160902110124_d2b2680b-c493-4986-aa84-f65794bfd8e4
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1472783047951_0004, Tracking URL = http://hadoop-master:8088/proxy/application_1472783047951_0004/
Kill Command = /opt/hadoop-2.6.4/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1472783047951_0004
```

The is nothing wrong with select *.

```
hive (default)> select * from newtb;
OK
1   2   3
1   3   4
2   3   4
5   6   7
8   9   0
1   8   3
Time taken: 0.101 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
```

So, I think there is something wrong with MapReduce. There is enough disk an memory. So, How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having issues because application master is unable to start containers and run the job. First try restarting your system and if it doesn't change  you have to change memory allocations in yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml. go with basic memory settings.

use Following links
http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide/#yarn-configuration_1

[here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)

[here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)

Comment: The easiest solution is to just save the default xml files and copy the config into `mapred-site.xml` and `yarn-site.xml` respectively

Answer (score 0):

As I was running hadoop on the ubuntu as a quest on the wmware, I just do increase the amount of RAM that I had been allocated to the ubuntu, I allocated 4GB Ram instead of 2GB Ram to the ubuntu, finally it could continue out and finished the job.